# How to achieve high-quality downscaling of diagrams (like in Firefox)?

Tags: firefox, gimp, scaling, image-processing, algorithm

I often need to downscale raster images consisting of thick straight lines and other thick curves, like this one:

[image: like this one].

Using GIMP 2.8.16 and its various interpolation options to resize the image to 600×600 sq. pixels, I obtain the following images:

**No interpolation**

[image: No interpolation]

**Linear**

[image: Linear]

**Cubic**

[image: Cubic]

**Sinc (Lanczos3)**

[image: Sinc]

Now, compare this to the result achieved by Firefox the web browser:

**Firefox 47.0**

[image: Firefox]

Look, for instance, at the topmost grey line. If you compare<sup>1</sup> each of the GIMP-produced images with the one obtained using Firefox carefully, you'll see that in each comparison, the line looks far better in the Firefox-generated image.

Now, as you might imagine, using a web browser to downscale images isn't very convenient, so I wonder if there is any image editor able to downscale images like this as nicely as Mozilla Firefox. I would prefer an easy way to do **batch** resizing.

<sup>1</sup> Make sure your browser isn't applying any interpolation of its own when you view the images. You might want to open a new browser window and open two tabs in it: one with a GIMP version, and the other with the Firefox version. Then use Ctrl+Tab to switch tab quickly. This will make the differences very obvious to most human observers.

Comment: You would probably get more feedback at [computergraphics.stackexchange](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Too bad GIMP still don't have gamma correction in 2016

Comment: Have you tried this in a current development build of GIMP as well?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: No, I have only tried it in the latest stable version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered that ImageMagick 7 produces a result as nice as the one obtained by Mozilla Firefox:

[image]

To resize an image using ImageMagick, use the command:

```
magick image.png -resize 600 small.png
```

This will resize `image.png` to a width of 600px, preserving the aspect ratio, and saves the output as `small.png`.

After some trial and error, I even found a way to do batch resizing using cmd.exe on Windows 7. The command:

```
for %f IN (*.png) DO magick %f -resize 600 scaled/%f
```

will resize all PNG images in the current directory to a width of 600px, preserving the aspect ratio, and placing the output images in the `scaled` subdirectory.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer adding the image generated with ImageMagic under windows? So it will be possible to do comparison. Thanks.

Comment: @Hastur: Sorry, can't believe I forgot to show the image. Will update in a sec.

Comment: Thanks. Since you recently _discovered_ Imagemagick, I would like to invite you to _play_ with `identify` (`identify -verbose yourimage.png`). It can give some hints. The original image was with only 4 colours; the other ones are not. Firefox adds an alpha channel not present in the IM one... With those hints you can start to play with the command line options (that are not commutative!) in the attempt to obtain an even better result (but you have to define your _better_). With no _computational time_ problems you may find interesting [povray](http://www.povray.org) (for your program).

Comment: Note: [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) is a fork of ImageMagic that has superior performance and quality.

Comment: @harrymc: Interesting. I'll remember that if I get tired of ImageMagick.

Comment: @harrymc is this still valid? The reason why GM was created was lack of stability of the IM API and CLI, IIRC - but I couldn't reference any examples for that myself. Do you know any current comparison of these projects?

Comment: Of course it's current and has much evolved since then. Last release was May 30, 2016.

Comment: I don't doubt that there is a current release of GraphicsMagick, and that at its initial conception it was better than ImageMagick - if not for quality, then at least for "Will the option I use still be present in the next micro release?". My question is, does this still hold provably true nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling looking for a good downscale(r) myself mostly used for scaling application screenshots for web documentation. my results:

1. *Photoshop*: `Bad`
2. *MS Word*: `Good` Insert the image on a document, re-size it, take a screen capture, save it as png with i.e. Paint.exe. The results are good but MS does not let you control the size by pixels (only inches or %).
3. **ReSize.exe** (from RoboHelp suite): `Good`
   But it does not directly handle png; I use this method now converting png->bmp-resize-bmp->png. This is my current choice.

Comment: Your option #2 is like how I did things (but using Firefox) before I 'discovered' ImageMagick! I opened the original PNG in Firefox, right-clicked the image (the <img> element), selected "Inspect element" and either changed the `width` and `height` attributes or added `width:600px` and `height:600px` to the local element style using the right-hand panel. Then I used the panel to remove the non-solid-colour background of the page, took a screenshot (using OneNote's tool) of the image and some padding around it, opened the screenshot in GIMP, auto-cropped it and saved it.

Comment: I should've said I also tested ImageMagic but in my case (reducing Windows application screenshots) it didn't do a good job when reducing displayed text. I have tested a lot; for me option 3 is the one that gives me the best results.

Comment: I can imagine the notion of 'best' actually depending quite a lot on the type of graphics. As far as text goes, perhaps it also matters whether or not it is anti-aliased. Also, in a a normal screenshot, much of the text probably consists of one-pixel-wide lines, whereas my sources have very thick lines. (Didn't downvote.)

Comment: (I know you didn't downvote ) I just wanted to contribute to this discussion with my experience. I agree my concept of "best" results it's based on  application screenshots which are mainly made of geometrical square shapes plus text. In your case you do not deal with text.

Comment: I think I will continue using ImageMagick, and the best result I have seen on this page comes from Photoshop. Still, thank you, and +1 for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can use photoshop's "bicubic sharper" option

Or you can scale using bicubic interpolation THEN "slightly" sharpen the image using gimp or whatever tool you want

https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-sharpen.html

https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-scale.html

[image]

This is photoshop's bicubic sharper
[image]

This is photoshop's bicubic smoother
[image]

This is what happens when you apply photoshop's "sharpen edges" and then use the normal bicubic interpolation. (I recommend this one). also, I zoomed in and compared this to the firefox output, they are very similar.
[image]

Comment: Photoshop, is not good for the task no matter what re-sampling method you decide to use nor the post processing you might use to "improve" the thing either. I own Adobe "Master Collection CS6", "eLearning SuiteCS6.1", and "Technical Suite 4"  They do not have anything good to downsize an image like the one presented here (well ReSize.exe is an old RoboHelp application owned by Adobe but it doesn't directly handle PNGs).

Comment: @Pat don't you like the latest picture I presented?

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: Thank you for your informative description of the options offered by Photoshop. The first result I don't like, sine the lines are clearly 'pixellated'. The second result, however, is almost indistinguishable from the Firefox/ImageMagick result; the difference is visible in the middle and to the right, and I am not sure, but perhaps Photoshop does an even better job there. The third result also looks very good, and the lines are clearly brighter (I don't mind that).

Comment: (But why the GIMP links at the top?)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand in the future, people who find this post after searching for something similar, may not have access to photoshop. also, people may want to produce similar results using command line tools for automation, so im trying to tell people about mathematical methods rather than what to click.

Comment: In this case Photoshop does what it looks like a good job but after using in for years I know PS is not my tool for resizing images.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: Sorry about the parenthesised question. I hadn't seen the text "using gimp or whatever tool you want" when I wrote it (I was way too busy comparing the bitmaps, investigating the subtle differences between them). I believe the second of your approaches gives the best result of all on this page, so you certainly deserve +1 and a 250 bounty for that! But I am not sure if I should select this answer or the ImageMagick one as the "accepted answer", because ImageMagick produces an *almost* equally nice image, is very efficient (even for batch use) and a bit more free than Photoshop.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I actually tried to explain the algorithms I am indifferent about the applications, the reason why I posted photoshop's examples is because I have photoshop installed. If you wanna try out algorithms other than bicubic or bilinear you can install imagemagick but you'll have to deal with the command line, and long documentations. I like all these tools.